# Is Botman using any Artificial Intelligence? Or it is just a coding method? (based on the codes below)

Tags: php, chatbot, botman

```
<?php
use App\BotMan\Conversations\OnboardingConversation;

$botman = app('botman');

$botman->hears('.*(hi|hey|hello|halo).*', function($bot) {
    $bot->typesAndWaits(1);
    $bot->reply('hello');
});
```

is the code above based on AI? Or is Botman involving any AI or ML?

Comment: `.*(hi|hey|hello|halo).*` looks like a regular expression, so it appears this is probably just looking for matches of specific given words - that's not AI.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code, it's use regular expression and using words and pattern matches, like AIML. However, you can also integrate Botman with Dialogflow(AI) to get user Intent and replies message based on the intent or directly used the dialogflow to make a reply.